Положение вставной конструкции

Только череда смертей известных музыкантов, вошедших в пресловутый «клуб 27» вследствие употребления веществ и алкоголя, (Дж. Хендрикс, Дж. Джоплин, Дж. Моррисон и др.), а также осуждение ЛСД со стороны ООН, за которым последовал запрет наркотика в большинстве стран мира, остудили всеобщий пыл.

Возможно ли поместить вставную конструкцию, связанную со словом «музыканты», после причастного оборота? И насколько уместно выглядит конструкция в скобках, стоящая между запятыми? Конечно, можно передвинуть оборот/конструкцию, но хотелось бы понять, корректен ли вариант, приведённый выше.

• Возможно ли поместить вставную конструкцию, связанную со словом «музыканты», после причастного оборота?
Возможно.
• Насколько уместно выглядит конструкция в скобках, стоящая между запятыми?
В этом предложении запятую перед скобкой никакими правилами обосновать невозможно. Запятая ставится только после вставной конструкции — она закрывает причастный оборот.
• Хотелось бы понять, корректен ли вариант, приведённый выше?
Корректен.
Необходимы, правда, исправления:
орфографическое — «Клуб 27» (название пишется с прописной буквы);
смысловые — слово "веществ" нуждается в определении (запрещенных, наркотических, вредных), имена музыкантов лучше написать полностью (а то все они у вас получились одинаковыми  — все "Дж.").
● Получаем (с изменениями):
Только череда смертей известных музыкантов, вошедших в пресловутый «Клуб 27» вследствие употребления одурманивающих веществ и алкоголя (Джими Хендрикс, Дженис Джоплин, Джим Моррисон и др.), а также осуждение ЛСД со стороны ООН, за которым последовал запрет наркотика в большинстве стран мира, остудили всеобщий пыл.
● Из правил Розенталя:

Примечание. Знаки препинания, которые стоят на месте «разрыва» предложения вставной конструкцией, выделяемой скобками, помещаются после скобок: <...> Татьяна, состоявшая, как мы уже сказали выше, в должности прачки (впрочем, ей, как искусной и учёной прачке, поручалось одно тонкое бельё), была женщина лет двадцати осьми (Т.) — здесь обособленное определение.

● Из статьи:
«Ранняя смерть часто ожидаема для тех, кто знаменит — возможно, как предупреждение и предостережение от излишеств, — заявил Кросс. — Это не тот клуб, в который большинство захотело бы вступить, поскольку в стоимость входного билета входит как слава, так и преждевременная смерть. По правде говоря, это вовсе не клуб, а название для группы некрологов».
[Чарльз Кросс — автор биографий Кобейна и Хендрикса.]
